# Frame and text issues for Subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, subplot

I am trying to get text next to the bars in this horizontal bar plot:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgcvj.png

However, the "Fullerton" name seems to be inside the red plot, but I want to move it outside it. The issue is that I would have to move ALL the text from each year the same way, and that would make some names super far right. Is there a way to manually move "Fullerton"?

2. Additionally, I would like to be able to control which parts of the "frame" I want included. I used the code axes[1].set(frame_on=False) but that removed EVERYTHING. I would like to have an x-axis line included.
3. Also, I would like to have the year numbers to be in the middle of the y-ticks.
4. Lastly, I am not sure how my subplots do not list every single year value (its from 2000 to 2020). I would like it to do so, but they are only every 5 years. I have tried many methods such as set_yticks but that does not seem to work.

My code is below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time
import itertools
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

Years = np.array([2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020])

S_scores = np.array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, -18, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39])

A_scores = np.array([40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60])



A_presidents = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"]
S_presidents = ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH", "II", "JJ", "KK", "LL", "MM", "NN", "OO", "PP", "QQ", "RR", "SS", "TT", "UU"]


regression_A = pd.DataFrame({
    "Years": Years,
    "A_scores": A_scores
})

lr = Ridge()
lr.fit(regression_A[['A_scores']], regression_A['Years'])
Ridge(alpha=1.0, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
   normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)

regression_S = pd.DataFrame({
    "Years": Years,
    "S_scores": S_scores
})

lr = Ridge()
lr.fit(regression_S[['S_scores']], regression_S['Years'])
Ridge(alpha=1.0, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
   normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True, sharex=False, figsize= (8,8))


A = axes[0].barh(Years, A_scores, align='center', color=np.where(A_scores < 0, 'red', 'green'))
axes[0].set_xlim(-40, 80)
axes[0].plot(regression_A["A_scores"], lr.coef_*regression_A['A_scores']+lr.intercept_, color='orange')
axes[0].plot(lr.coef_*regression_A['Years']+lr.intercept_, regression_A["Years"], color='purple')
axes[0].set_xlabel("A Score")
axes[0].set(frame_on=False)  # Remove all the framing
axes[0].yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
axes[0].vlines  

S = axes[1].barh(Years, S_scores, align='center', color=np.where(S_scores < 0, 'red', 'green'))
axes[1].set_xlim(-40, 80)
axes[1].set_ylabel("Years")
axes[1].yaxis.set_label_position("right")

axes[1].set_xlabel("S Score")
axes[1].set(frame_on=False)  # Remove all the framing


axes[1].plot(regression_S["S_scores"], lr.coef_*regression_S['S_scores']+lr.intercept_, color='orange')
axes[1].plot(lr.coef_*regression_S['Years']+lr.intercept_, regression_S["Years"], color='purple')


rects2 = A.patches

for rect, label in zip(A, A_presidents):
    width = rect.get_width() + 2
    label_y_pos = rect.get_y() + (rect.get_height() / 2)
    axes[0].text(width, label_y_pos, s=label, color='blue')#, ha="right", va="top")


rects1 = S.patches

for rect, label in zip(S, S_presidents):
    width = rect.get_width() + 2
    label_y_pos = rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2
    axes[1].text(width, label_y_pos, s=label, color='blue')#, ha="right", va="top")
   
###TRENDLINE CODE###
import statsmodels.api as sm

resA = stats.theilslopes(Years, A_scores, 0.90)
lsq_resA = stats.linregress(A_scores, Years)
resS = stats.theilslopes(Years, S_scores, 0.90)
lsq_resS = stats.linregress(S_scores, Years)

axes[0].plot(A_scores, resA[1] + resA[0] * A_scores, '--', color="black", label="Thiel-Sen Regression Line")`

axes[1].plot(S_scores, resS[1] + resS[0] * S_scores, '--', color="black", label="Thiel-Sen Regression Line")

plt.tight_layout()
```

S_presidents is just an list with the names for each year. S_scores is also just a list with the score associated for each year.

Thank you!

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll edit and provide sample data!

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I've added in the data and looked at the minimal example. Thanks!

Comment: The code still won't run. Even after importing the modules you need, you are plotting undefined variables.

Comment: Can you declare a variable that defines the horizontal_alignment (`ha = "left"`) and then have if statement that catches the Fullerton case so `if Fullerton: ha = "right"`?

Comment: @wikikikitiki just fixed the code, sorry for all the issues! I just tried it and it gives me a plot, let me know if its still not working for you. I will try out your suggestion and report back, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modification points

1. Placement of string annotations
   If the value is negative and the position information is set to 0, it will be placed on the right side; if 0 is too close to the y-axis, it can be changed arbitrarily by changing the value.
2. Graph frame control
   Set the frame control to lower only.
3. Center the year tick marks
   Adjust the spacing of the subplots manually, and turn off the automatic adjustment of tight_layout().
4. Set y-axis year scale from 2010 to 2020
   Create a scale interval for the y-axis and set the notation for the ticks.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True, sharex=False, figsize= (8,8))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.18) # update

A = axes[0].barh(Years, A_scores, align='center', color=np.where(A_scores < 0, 'red', 'green'))
axes[0].set_xlim(-40, 80)
axes[0].plot(regression_A["A_scores"], lr.coef_*regression_A['A_scores']+lr.intercept_, color='orange')
axes[0].plot(lr.coef_*regression_A['Years']+lr.intercept_, regression_A["Years"], color='purple')
axes[0].set_xlabel("A Score")
#axes[0].set(frame_on=False)  # Remove all the framing
axes[0].yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
axes[0].vlines  
axes[0].spines['top'].set_visible(False) # update
axes[0].spines['left'].set_visible(False) # update
axes[0].spines['right'].set_visible(False) # update
axes[0].set_yticks(np.arange(2000,2021,1)) # update
axes[0].set_yticklabels(np.arange(2000,2021,1)) # update

S = axes[1].barh(Years, S_scores, align='center', color=np.where(S_scores < 0, 'red', 'green'))
axes[1].set_xlim(-40, 80)
axes[1].set_ylabel("Years")
axes[1].yaxis.set_label_position("right")

axes[1].set_xlabel("S Score")
#axes[1].set(frame_on=False)  # Remove all the framing
axes[1].spines['top'].set_visible(False) # update
axes[1].spines['left'].set_visible(False) # update
axes[1].spines['right'].set_visible(False) # update

axes[1].plot(regression_S["S_scores"], lr.coef_*regression_S['S_scores']+lr.intercept_, color='orange')
axes[1].plot(lr.coef_*regression_S['Years']+lr.intercept_, regression_S["Years"], color='purple')

rects2 = A.patches

for rect, label in zip(A, A_presidents):
    width = rect.get_width() + 2
    label_y_pos = rect.get_y() + (rect.get_height() / 2)
    axes[0].text(width, label_y_pos, s=label, color='blue')#, ha="right", va="top")


rects1 = S.patches

for rect, label in zip(S, S_presidents):
    width = rect.get_width() + 2
    if width < 0: # update
        width = 0 # update
    label_y_pos = rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2
    axes[1].text(width, label_y_pos, s=label, color='blue')#, ha="right", va="top")
    
#plt.tight_layout() # update

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any requests for additional customization? If my answer is helpful to you, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark under the reputation up/down button.

Comment: Hi! This was so extremely helpful, thank you so much! I had one more question, how can I create more separation between the two graphs? For example, some of my names are crossing over the border and entering the "years" section.

Comment: One example is to change the limit of the X axis. `axes[0].set_xlim(0, 80)` Leave the right side of each bar chart empty.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. Lastly, any suggestion on getting the years to be perfectly centered between the two plots. For my plot, the years tend to be closer to the left side.

Comment: sorry not sure if you were responding to my question!

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, so I was translating and made a mistake in the operation. When 'tight_layout()' is enabled, it automatically adjusts the spacing, so I deactivated it because it doesn't have the effect of fine tuning.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the last question I promise, but I'm worried about x-axis backtracking, since when I try to add a trendline (code below), I don't get proper dashed lines: https://imgur.com/a/RwC9SHm

Code for the trendline added to the original comment.

Comment: I was able to confirm this by drawing only two orange lines. I guessed that the distance between the dots was too short, so it looked like a continuous line even if it was a dashed line. Try specifying `ls='dotted'` as the line style type.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. Also, regarding the spacing, I used tight_layout() but I still got some spacing issues: https://imgur.com/a/fQB11HG . Any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out, just need to adjust fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.85)!